# doing something wrong in pointing the values in a structure

Tags: coldfusion

I have this gist code do i need to use a struct to append the values, not sure what is going on in here

```
<cfscript>
ex = {};
s = '8734568';
k = 'MyStr';
writedump(ex[s][k]);
</cfscript>
```

what i am doing wrong in here, do i need to wrap it with string, i tried but not working

tried like this

```
writedump(ex['#s#']['#k#']);
```

https://trycf.com/gist/6acdc5e495061dc0c59103c924241210/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access elements of the struct that do not yet exists. You have to set them first. For example...

```
<cfscript>
ex = {};
s = '8734568';
k = 'MyStr';
ex[s] = k;
writedump(ex);
</cfscript>
```